# Keil Blank Areas

Tags: area, keil

I need to know how to put blank areas into hex file (not used memory). At this moment All blank areas are removed from my hex file. Normally it is not a problem, but I need to generate the same hex file like that one which was sent to customer. Any idea how to do it?